# I am notified about old comments instead of new ones

Tags: bug, comments, notifications

I have three notifications pending but when I open the tab they were a month ago. When I refresh the page I see the correct three notifications. Pictures:

Here you see notifications from March but it is April:

[image: Three old notifications highlighted]

Here I refreshed the page and recognized that there are indeed three unread notifications.

[image: The real three notifications not highlighted]

This behavior occurred already three times before, always with the spinlock question as first comment. Today I finally realized that there were indeed notifications pending.

Is this a bug to report? If this is not the right side to ask about this - where should I go to?

**Edit 1**

Browser: Firefox 28.0 (current version) Windows 7 on a Laptop

It only appears on the favourites side. When I open [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228500/why-am-i-notified-about-old-comments-instead-of-new-ones) I see the current comments.

**Edit 2**

On favourites I see the old issue [image]

On meta and stackoverflow I see the new comment [image]

**Edit3**

Still an issue on April 11th and April 16th.
The question is more like: Can somebody remove this or show me a way to remove it or let it remove?

**Edit4**

April 20th at 14:00GMT the favourite tags turned into an error page: [Broken Favourite Tags Link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251381/broken-favourite-tags-link)

Comment: Which browser is that?  I'm inclined to blame caching.  No, I'm not trying to be funny.

Comment: I have recently noticed that I receive notifications about comments for the second time (I already saw a notification for that comment and read it) after ~5 hours. Chrome.